# How to write this mySQL query to show many data per one column?

Tags: php, mysql

My mySQL table is as below

```
id - hash - page - timestamp
1 - ig35sdf89 - page1 - 2015-05-06 12:03:54
2 - ig35sdf89 - page2 - 2015-05-06 12:06:54
3 - ig35sdf89 - page1 - 2015-05-06 12:08:54
4 - xgd98rgf - page1 - 2015-05-06 12:10:54
5 - aaaat43gr - page3 - 2015-05-06 12:12:54
```

My question is what is a mySQL query to use so as to show something like where I will show the path of each hash order by his timestamp:

```
ig35sdf89  - page1 - 2015-05-06 12:08:54
           - page2 - 2015-05-06 12:03:54
           - page1 - 2015-05-06 12:06:54

xgd98rgf  - page1 - 2015-05-06 12:10:54

aaaat43gr  - page3 - 2015-05-06 12:12:54
```

I am using PHP.

Comment: Mysql is not for generating these kind of view, thats the job of the application level.

Comment: As I understand the question, you should look at [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) sql statement.

Comment: use [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty any way of developing this mysql+php is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql supports [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Which supports exactly this use case

So if your table is defined as

**table defn**

```
create table pages
(
  id integer auto_increment primary key not null,
  hash varchar(10) not null,
  pagename varchar(128) not null,
  last_access_time timestamp not null
);
```

You can use this

**query**

```
select 
hash, group_concat(pagename, last_access_time SEPARATOR ';\n')
from
pages
group by hash
;
```

or alternatively can return json to use with php [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) :

**query output json**

```
select 
concat('{', prty_hash, ',"pages":[', group_concat(json_page SEPARATOR ','), ']}') as json_prt
from
(
select 
concat('"hash":"', hash, '"') as prty_hash,
concat('"page":', pagename) as prty_pagename,
concat('{', '"page":"', pagename, '",', '"last_access_time":"', last_access_time, '"}') as json_page
from
pages
) prty
group by prty_hash
;
```

this gives

**json output**

> {"hash":"123456789","pages":[{"page":"mypage3","last_access_time":"2015-05-06
>   09:34:02"},{"page":"mypage2","last_access_time":"2015-05-06
>   09:34:02"},{"page":"mypage1","last_access_time":"2015-05-06
>   09:34:02"}]}
>
> {"hash":"999999","pages":[{"page":"mypage4","last_access_time":"2015-05-06
>   09:34:02"}]}

link to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c0c4/7)

This can now be consumed in php something like :

**php**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = ...;
$password = ...;
$dbname = ...;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// GET
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET")
{
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     } 

    $sql = <<<heredoc
      select 
      concat('{', prty_hash, ',"pages":[', group_concat(json_page SEPARATOR ','), ']}') as json_prt
      from
      (
        select 
        concat('"hash":"', hash, '"') as prty_hash,
        concat('"page":', pagename) as prty_pagename,
        concat('{', '"page":"', pagename, '",',       '"last_access_time":"', last_access_time, '"}') as json_page
        from
        pages
      ) prty
      group by prty_hash
      ;
heredoc;

    $dbResult = $conn->query($sql);
    $appResult = array();

    while($row = $dbResult->fetch_assoc()) {
        $json_res_obj = json_decode($row['json_prt']);  
        // do something with the object, render/echo it on the page etc..
    }

    $conn->close();
}
else
{
    die("Invalid request");
}


?>
```

Note: untested php..

Comment: Thank you but how do i display it using PHP ?

Comment: Thank you for this and you got my upvote, however I don't know how to execute the second example through `mysql_query()` because of the `""`. Also, when i ran the first example, the `concat` diidn't show everything but stopped somewhere.

Comment: in php can escape quote characters with a backslash [ \ ] character, so eg. an example: "this is a \"string within a\" string".  and be sure to use the current php interfaces - should be using [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: OK thank you I did the escape. However how can I show it. Sorry but I am a beginner and learn by example...

Comment: And also, what is the `prty` I mean is it correct at the 3 row of bottom ?

Comment: Thankyou.. can you please tell me how to show the results?

Comment: Thanks!! i got it running using `echo row['json_prt']` one last thing however, how do I output it as the example? how do I call for example the has, all the pages with timestamps, next hash..

Comment: you will have to loop over the json_decoded object `pages` array, and render them in a table or div or however you want to structure your page output

Comment: Can you please give me the code ? I am echo pages['hash'] without luck

Comment: @poulokopri search ( or start a new question with your current code ) for accessing json objects from php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077247/how-can-i-echo-this-json-in-this-specific-output

Comment: Hello I try to validate the output json, however it does not validate

Answer (score 0):

Mysql don`t suppor this thing, because have table structure.
The most right way is to create PHP function to convert array. For example:

```
function convertArray($result) {
    $comparator = '';
    foreach($result as $row) {
        if ($comparator != $row['hash']) {
             $comparator = $row['hash'];
             $array[$comparator][] = $row;
        } else {
          $array[$comparator][] = $row;
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Thank you but can you post me the sql query too ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM [tableName];

Comment: And how do i call the function ?

Comment: From native php?

`mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("CONNECT ERROR");`</br>
`mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF-8");` </br>
`mysql_select_db($DB) OR DIE("Database not exist");` </br>
`$result = mysql_query("SELECt * FROM [yourTableName]");` </br>

Comment: Yes, after i `mysql_query`

Comment: From native php?

`mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("CONNECT ERROR");`
`mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF-8");`
`mysql_select_db($DB) OR DIE("Database not exist");`
`$result = mysql_query("SELECt * FROM [yourTableName]");`

Comment: Thank you but what is the PHP code that will call the `convertarray` function

Comment: After this use:
`while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result){.....code.....}`
for access every row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(@tempHash = `hash`, '', @tempHash := `hash`) `hash`, page, `timestamp` 
FROM myTable
JOIN (SELECT @tempHash := '')s
ORDER BY `hash`, `timestamp`
```

Is it satisfying your conditions?

EDIT : Changed order by fields
Added hash also

Comment: I tested and even though it runs, it has a bug. The path (pages) of user `abc` are splitted. I mean that it displays a number of pages, then a user `xxx123` is shown and then it continues with user `abc`. What I want is full list of `abc` and then proceed to `xxx123` and so on.

Comment: I noticed in the results that the splitting is made by timestamp. but it has to be per hash (user)

Comment: I have changed the order by clause to accomodate your requirment

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this...

For table structure like   ==>   hash_page(id,hash,page,timestamp)

```
<?php    
//this sql query groups all rows with same 'hash' value
$sql = "SELECT hash_page.id,hash_page.hash,GROUP_CONCAT(hash_page.page) as hash_pages,GROUP_CONCAT(hash_page.timestamp) as timestamps FROM hash_page GROUP BY hash";

$result = mysql_query($sql);


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

//this will explode comma seperated values to array
$hash_pages_arr = explode(',',$row['hash_pages']);
$timestamps_arr = explode(',',$row['timestamps']);
$count_arr = count($hash_pages_arr);

$page_timestamp_arr = array();
for($i=0; $i<$count_arr; $i++){

    $page_timestamp_arr[] = array('page'=>$hash_pages_arr[$i],'timestamp'=>$timestamps_arr[$i]);
}

$new_result[$row['hash']] = $page_timestamp_arr;
}


echo '<pre>';print_r($new_result);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you but group concat will not get me the whole list, it will break after a number of chars

Comment: sorry but i am not getting what you want to say.

it will break after a number of chars? means what

Comment: The chars when you combine all the `page` are very long. group_concat has a maximum length