# How can I echo this JSON in this specific output?

Tags: php, json

How can I echo this json in this format?

```
123456789 - mypage3 - 2015-05-06 09:34:02
          - mypage2 - 2015-05-06 09:34:02
          - mypage1 - 2015-05-06 09:34:02

999999    - mypage4 - 2015-05-06 09:34:02
```

here is the JSON

```
{"hash":"123456789","pages":[{"page":"mypage3","last_access_time":"2015-05-06 09:34:02"},{"page":"mypage2","last_access_time":"2015-05-06 09:34:02"},{"page":"mypage1","last_access_time":"2015-05-06 09:34:02"}]}

{"hash":"999999","pages":[{"page":"mypage4","last_access_time":"2015-05-06 09:34:02"}]}
```

Here is what I have now:

```
$appResult = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $json_res_obj = json_decode($row['json_prt']);  
    echo $row[json_prt];
}
```

Comment: what does `echo $json_res_obj->{'pages'};` return ?

Comment: @amdixon it returns ArrayArrayArray........

Answer (score 1):

Consider this PHP code here, it's only for the first JSON string, but you get the idea:

```
<?php 

$json = '{
    "hash": "123456789",
    "pages": [
        {
            "page": "mypage3",
            "last_access_time": "2015-05-06 09:34:02"
        },
        {
            "page": "mypage2",
            "last_access_time": "2015-05-06 09:34:02"
        },
        {
            "page": "mypage1",
            "last_access_time": "2015-05-06 09:34:02"
        }
    ]
}';

$data = json_decode($json,true);


echo $data['hash'] . " - ";

foreach($data['pages'] as $rows) {
  echo $rows['page'] . " - " . $rows['last_access_time'] . "<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Please follow my code `$appResult = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $json_res_obj = json_decode($row['json_prt']);  
    //magic happens here I guess
}`

Comment: Erm, it's up to you to put it into practice. I'm giving you a working solution, I'm sure you can work it out from there.

Comment: I understand, but I am a beginner this is why I am asking it. Also there is not one hash, there are severals

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
    <?php

    $data = '{"hash":"123456789","pages":[{"page":"mypage3","last_access_time":"2015-05-06 09:34:02"},{"page":"mypage2","last_access_time":"2015-05-06 09:34:02"},{"page":"mypage1","last_access_time":"2015-05-06 09:34:02"}]}';
    $data = json_decode($data);
    echo $data->hash . "<br>";
    $pages = $data->pages;
    if(isset($data->pages)){
      foreach($pages as $key => $value){
            echo $value->page . "-" . $value->last_access_time . "<br>";
     }
   }

?>
```

Comment: In some cases, i do not know which I get Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code adding some format

```
$row['json_prt'] = '{"hash":"123456789","pages":[{"page":"mypage3","last_access_time":"2015-05-06 09:34:02"},{"page":"mypage2","last_access_time":"2015-05-06 09:34:02"},{"page":"mypage1","last_access_time":"2015-05-06 09:34:02"}]}';
    $json_res_obj = json_decode($row['json_prt']);  

    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($json_res_obj->pages as $page) 
        echo ' - '.$page->page.' - '.$page->last_access_time.'<br>';
```

UPDATE:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $json_res_obj = json_decode($row['json_prt']);  

        echo '<pre>';
        foreach($json_res_obj->pages as $page) 
            echo ' - '.$page->page.' - '.$page->last_access_time.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: In some cases, i do not know which I get Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Add print_($json_res_obj). it must help

Comment: Can you please wrap your suggested code with my actual code that I use mysql ?